# NameError at /register/ name 'user' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am currently developing a blogging webapp and I tried to extend my Django User Framework With a One To One Field, everything is working fine, but when I'm trying to register a new user, it's throwing a NameError. It is also worth noting that the user is being created and stored(I checked it from the admin page). It is saying that this statement `profile.user = user` in my views.py is creating the problem. Can anyone please help me with this?

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, ProfileForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user  
            profile.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    CHOICES = (
        ('AB+', 'AB+'),
        ('AB-', 'AB-'),
        ('A+', 'A+'),
        ('A-', 'A-'),
        ('B+', 'B+'),
        ('B-', 'B-'),
        ('O+', 'O+'),
        ('O-', 'O-'),
        )
    bloodgroup = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices= CHOICES)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('image', 'bloodgroup', 'bio')
```

Comment: What do you expect `user` to be in `profile.user = user`? You never define a variable with that name.

Answer (score 1):

`profile.user = user` change to `profile.user = request.user`

Comment: Now it says :  `Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.`

Comment: Now it says : `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

Comment: you should logged in to handle this error, you can use a login required decorator in this view

Comment: Where should I add login required?

Comment: no, it is wrong, try to assign from User.object.get(user=request.user), otherwise you have to use pre save signal instead of this way

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

instead of

```
from django.contrib.auth import User
```